# AppDelegate dealloc gets called before program starts

Tags: ios, dealloc

I am experiencing a very weird situation that crashes my app when running on device. When I run my app on iphone from xcode, I got an error saying I am trying to access an AppDelegate property that has been deallocated. So I track it down and noticed that everytime my app starts it goes straight to AppDelegate dealloc method before getting applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. It therefore deallocated all my properties. The strange thing is all the interface looks normal even though the appDelegate has been deallocated, only has problem later when I access a property from AppDelegate. Also another weird thing is even though it does the same thing (calling dealloc() first) when running on iOS simulator, the app runs without any error. Can anyone help me explain this? Thanks.

PS: One thing I am suspecting is that recently I have revoked and recreated my certificate which led to changing code singing identity on my project. However I did it correctly and able to run it on the phone so not sure if it is the problem.

Comment: How is your app delegate created? Do you have its class name as an argument to the main function (in `main.m`), or is it an object in your main nib?

Comment: This link provide a detailed explanation!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685025/why-system-call-uiapplicationdelegates-dealloc-method