# Delalloc Call before DidFinishLoading in AppDelegate Class

Tags: iphone, dealloc

In my application when I run it with xcode 4.2 it working perfectly but when I run it with xcode 4.5 then I find a critical error there. I found that `Dealloc` method of ApplicationDelegate call First, even it call before `DidFinishLaunching` and then application.

I have been surfing for this stuff since last much time bud didn't get any solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you put an example of your code?

Comment: it's simple as always we code... nothing new new in code. it just call dealloc first in xcode 4.5 while it working properly in xcode 4.2

Comment: This might help you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685025/why-system-call-uiapplicationdelegates-dealloc-method