# Transform UIApplicationDelegate methods into RxSwift Observables

Tags: ios, swift, observable, uiapplicationdelegate, rx-swift

In RxSwift / RxCocoa you can create a reactive wrapper for a delegate (e.g. `UIScrollViewDelegate` or `CLLocationManagerDelegate`) to enable Rx observable sequences for certain delegate methods.

I am trying to implement this for the `UIApplicationDelegate` method `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

What I tried so far is pretty straightforward and similar to the `DelegateProxy` subclasses that are included in RxCocoa.

I created my `DelegateProxy` subclass:

```
class RxUIApplicationDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy, UIApplicationDelegate, DelegateProxyType {

    static func currentDelegateFor(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject? {
        let application: UIApplication = object as! UIApplication
        return application.delegate
    }

    static func setCurrentDelegate(delegate: AnyObject?, toObject object: AnyObject) {
        let application: UIApplication = object as! UIApplication
        application.delegate = delegate as? UIApplicationDelegate
    }
}
```

And an Rx extension for `UIApplication`:

```
extension UIApplication {
    public var rx_delegate: DelegateProxy {
        return proxyForObject(RxUIApplicationDelegateProxy.self, self)
    }

    public var rx_applicationDidBecomeActive: Observable<Void> {
        return rx_delegate.observe("applicationDidBecomeActive:")
            .map { _ in
                return
            }
    }
}
```

In my AppDelegate I subscribe to the observable:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // the usual setup
    // and then:
    application.rx_applicationDidBecomeActive
        .subscribeNext { _ in
            print("Active!")
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    return true
}
```

When I start my app "Active!" gets printed and then I get the following crash in RxCocoa's `_RXDelegateProxy_` class:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be? Or has anybody successfully implemented something like `rx_applicationDidBecomeActive`?

Comment: What exactly is `aSelector`?

Comment: `aSelector = (SEL) "window"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a really tricky issue with RxSwift and memory management.

The default implementation of `DelegateProxyType` sets an instance of a delegate proxy (in this case, `RxUIApplicationDelegateProxy`) to the `delegate` of `UIApplication`.

It also stores the original `AppDelegate` as a property called `forwardToDelegate` so all the delegate methods can still be passed to it.

The problem is that, when the new app delegate is set:

```
 application.delegate = delegate as? UIApplicationDelegate
```

the original one is deallocated! You can check it by overriding `deinit` in `AppDelegate`. The reasons are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271150/2128900). And because the property `forwardToDelegate` is of type `assign`, your app crashes as the property points to a deallocated object.

I have found a workaround for that. I'm not really sure if it is a recommended way, so be warned. You can override a method from `DelegateProxyType` in `RxUIApplicationDelegateProxy`:

```
  override func setForwardToDelegate(delegate: AnyObject?, retainDelegate: Bool) {
    super.setForwardToDelegate(delegate, retainDelegate: true)
  }
```

In normal circumstances, you don't want to retain the delegate as it leads to a retain cycle. But in this special case, this is not a problem: your `UIApplication` object will exist the entire time while your application is alive anyway.

Comment: Your suggested solution indeed fixes the problem. Thanks a lot for taking the time to find and explain the problem!